# Update Tomcat 7.0.52 to 7.0.53 on 14.04 Server

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to find a way to upgrade 7.0.52 to 7.0.53, but I can't not find a easy way to do it. Ubuntu installed 7.0.52 by default, I am looking to install later versions though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just use the standalone binary provided by Apache which you can download here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.53/bin/ (either apache-tomcat-7.0.53.zip or apache-tomcat-7.0.53.tar.gz).

Comment: You should include installation instructions.

Comment: Do you have any install instructions for this? Also - if I upgrade will this break anything currently running on the Tomcat server(my assumption is yes, but i wanted to double check)